# Components not rendered in React when created in function

Tags: reactjs, devexpress, devextreme

I'm rendering various DevExtreme editor components but while re-factoring some of my code and putting each of the editors into separate sfc or class components, it no longer renders the components.

The following works:

```
createFields(items) {
    return items.map((item) => {
        return (
            <SimpleItem
              key={item.itemId}
              dataField={item.fieldName} />
        );
    });
}
```

but the following doesn't:

```
import CreateTextBox from "./../fields/createTextBox";
import CreateNumberBox from "./../fields/createNumberBox";

createFields(items) {
    return items.map((item) => {
        return this.createField(item);
    });
}

createField(item) {
    switch (item.type) {
        case "text":
            return <CreateTextBox item={item} key={item.itemId} />;
        case "numeric":
            return <CreateNumberBox item={item} key={item.itemId} />;
    }
}
```

and I have a separate file for each of my editors contains the following:

```
import React from "react";
import { SimpleItem } from "../../../node_modules/devextreme-react/form";

const CreateTextBox = (item) => {     
    return (
       <SimpleItem key={item.itemId} 
                   dataField={item.fieldName} 
                   editorType='dxTextBox'
       />);
};

export default CreateTextBox;
```

The above is for the Textbox editor.

Note that converting sfc into a class made no difference.

I'm not getting any errors or warnings and I've check the item when in the sfc and it is definitely being set and when trying it with the class instead, my state is definitely being set correctly.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use props for your component input properties

```js
import React from "react";
import { SimpleItem } from "../../../node_modules/devextreme-react/form";

const CreateTextBox = (props) => {     
    return (
       <SimpleItem key={props.item?.itemId} 
                   dataField={props.item.fieldName} 
                   editorType='dxTextBox'
       />);
};

export default CreateTextBox;
```

or you can extract the props in the params like this:

```js
const CreateTextBox = ({item}) => {     
    return (
       <SimpleItem key={item?.itemId}
```